# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() using Kotlin

Tags: android, sql, jdbc, kotlin

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            callPostReq()
            val sm = someTask()
            sm.execute()
        }
inner class someTask(): AsyncTask<String, Int, Array<String>>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): Array<String>?  {
        val conn: Connection= null!!
        val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
        val dbName = "db-01"
        val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        val cred = Properties()
        cred.put("username","username")
        cred.put("password","pasword")

        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance()
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,cred)
            println("Connected to the database")
            conn.close()
            println("Disconnected from database")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                     Process: highway.dueamount, PID: 15746
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>                      Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                         at highway.dueamount.MainActivity$someTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.kt:60)
>                         at highway.dueamount.MainActivity$someTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.kt:57)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

Comment: Hi, your MYSQL server is running on your PC, but your Android device won't be able to see it. So you should write a REST API that connects to the database which can send the data over to the Android device in a reasonable format like JSON

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unwrap null. Just remove !! and it will work

```
val conn: Connection= null
```